# how to create a class in which it is necessary to throws or catch a specific exception.

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class FilenotFound_Demo {

   public static void main(String args[]){      
      File file=new File("E://file.txt");
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(file); 
   }

}
```

suppose i have the following code and if i compile it then

```
C:\>javac FilenotFound_Demo.java
FilenotFound_Demo.java:8: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
                      ^
1 error
```

how can i implement this functionality in a class that whenever i use that class it show the same type of error that it is necessary to catch or throw a specific exception.

Comment: Just declare that the method/constructor throws the given checked exception...

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the "throws" to your method.

```
public class TestClass {
    public TestClass() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception("Errormessage");
    }
}
```

This Exceptions has to be checked, which means it mustn't be inherited from RuntimeException. Doing that, the one who uses your class has to handle the exception. You can also use this at normal methods, not only the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It's a compilation error. So if you want that your class would behave like that just create a class which methods `throws` Checked Exception and call the method.

For example, in your example `new FileReader(file);` constructor `throws FileNotFoundException` thats why its not compiling without handling this exception.

```
public FileReader(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    super(new FileInputStream(file));
}
```

So, you could make your method something like that `public void expMethod() throws Exception{}` and call it in the class you need to show the `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
public class Overflow extends Exception{

public Overflow(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("s");
    File file=new File("E://file.txt");
    try{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    }catch(Exception e){
         new Overflow("File not found " +e);
    }
}
```

Output-

```
s
File not found java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\file.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```